# How to configure Glassfish on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Connection Pool and Realm

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, glassfish, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I developed a Java EE 7 application, that uses Glassfish as the application server and MySQL as the database.

locally every thing is working correctly

now, I want to deploy the application to the cloud using AWS.

after reading some official documentations:

I created The database in the cloud 'AWS RDS', and conneted to it from MySQL Workbench and also The application in my workspace was able to connect to it and act on it.

Now for The application deployment I used Elastic Beanstalk with Glassfish 4.1 Java 8 (the docker one).

The probleme is that I need to configure Glassfish In AWS to

1. Create JDBC Connection Pool
2. Create JDBC Resource
3. Create A Security Realm

so that the apllication can work correctly.

How Can I do This?

Comment: Do you have all of the commands to run in a `asadmin` script?  You'd need to run this script before deploying your application.  An alternative would be to get a copy of the config file and, after putting it on S3, get a copy of it and put it in the right place before starting.

Comment: @stdunbar yes I have all of them. But how Can I run them on aws glassfish???

Comment: Ultimately you'll want to take advantage of [deployment hooks](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/29-aws-elasticbeanstalk-deployment-hooks) to run your scripts.  It's great you have these as scripts as it makes it much easier to run them as post deploy hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch to Jelastic, I can access admin page usign their cloud, and I already deployed my appication